# Youtube API v3 processing abandoned after uploading

Tags: go, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a youtube video using Go. I do get a response of 200 OK but the video shows as processing abandoned on youtube studio

This is my full code:

```
func UploadVideo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    youtubeAuthToken := r.Header.Get("Authorization")

    const maxFileSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 // 50 GB
    r.ParseMultipartForm(maxFileSize)

    //file, handler, err := r.FormFile("videoFile")
    //
    //if err != nil {
    //  // Handle the error
    //  http.Error(w, "Failed to get video file", http.StatusBadRequest)
    //  return
    //}
    //defer file.Close()

    // FOR TESTING

    filePath := "D:\\feed-prototype\\internal\\services\\video.mp4" // Specify the path to your video file
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to open the video file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    // FOR TESTING

    //  creating a buffer to store the form data
    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    //  Adding video file to the request
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("video/*", "video.mp4") // use handler.FileName when formData
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to create form file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    _, err = io.Copy(part, file)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to copy file data", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    //  Video meta data
    var videoData utils.VideoData
    videoData.Snippet.Title = "My Video Title"
    videoData.Snippet.Description = "My Video Description"
    videoData.Snippet.Tags = []string{"tag1", "tag2", "tag3"}
    videoData.Snippet.CategoryId = "22" // Specify the category ID for your video
    videoData.Snippet.DefaultLanguage = "en-US"
    videoData.Status.PrivacyStatus = "private"

    metadata, err := json.Marshal(videoData)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to marshal video metadata", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    metaPart, err := writer.CreateFormField("json")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to create form field", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    _, err = metaPart.Write(metadata)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to write form field data", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    err = writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to close multipart writer", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    //  Creating HTTP request
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&part=status"+"&key="+apiKey+"&access_token="+youtubeAuthToken, body)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to create request", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")

    // Sending the request
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to send request", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    responseBody, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to read response", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Handle the response
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        fmt.Println(resp)
        http.Error(w, "Failed to upload video: "+resp.Status, http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Process the response body as needed
    fmt.Println(string(responseBody))

    // Return a success message
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte("Video uploaded successfully"))
}
```

I manually take the video from the same directory

I am getting this response:

```
  "kind": "youtube#video",
  "etag": "sZkdG8TxLSa-eDstdXTs9Iw887I",
  "id": "16wibcpe9ts",
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2023-06-06T14:00:05Z",
    "channelId": "UCKlDRAs3yyCLTqhVnrCrVBQ",
    "title": "unknown",
    "description": "",
    "license": "youtube",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicStatsViewable": true
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me out what the problem is. Am I properly sending the video file and the metadata to the YouTube API? Video is in mp4 format and is playable on my computer. It's just 3 seconds long.

Comment: Why not use the [VideosInsertCall](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3#VideosInsertCall) in the `google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3` package?